# Waiting in a redux-saga

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, redux-saga

I want to introduce a delay in a saga (using redux-saga).

How can I do this?

If redux-saga provides an API, I would also be interested in how to achieve it manually.

```
function* save({ payload }) {
    yield put(pending());
    // I want to simply wait (non-blocking) here for say 2 seconds
    yield put(complete());
}
```

Comment: See the `delay` function mentioned in the [tutorial](https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/introduction/BeginnerTutorial.html).

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Redux-sagas has [a special effect](https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/api/index.html#delayms-val) for this:

> delay(ms, [val])
>
> Returns a Promise that will resolve after ms milliseconds with val.

Example:

```
import { delay, call } from 'redux-saga/effects'

function* someSaga(input) {
  yield put(someAction())
  yield delay(500)
  yield put(anotherAction())
}
```

Comment: delay is in 'redux-saga/effects' not in redux-saga

Comment: @Pasalino that happened after version v1. Thank you to pointed out. I will update my answer.

Comment: instead of writing `yield call(delay, 5000)` where delay is an effect from `redux-saga/effects` you should write `yield delay(5000)` (quoting my console error :) )

Comment: @TecHunter why we should use `yield delay(5000)` instead of `yield call(delay, 5000)`? Can you explain more specifically?

Answer (score 3):

You could achieve that with a promise and a generator function:

```
function sleep(sec) { 
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, sec*1000)); 
}

function* save({ payload }) {
    yield put(pending());
    yield sleep(2); //wait 2 seconds
    yield put(complete());
}
```

Comment: Would you need to `yield` the sleep promise?

Comment: You need to do something - as written this will call `sleep` (returning a promise) and then immediately throw it away! If you yield a `call()` then redux-saga will wait for the promise to resolve, e.g.: `yield call(sleep, 2)`. The best solution is in the answer above - using the `delay` utility function.

Answer (score 0):

[Source](https://github.com/redux-saga/redux-saga/blob/master/src/internal/utils.js#L99).

```
export function delay(ms, val = true) {
  let timeoutId
  const promise = new Promise(resolve => {
    timeoutId = setTimeout(() => resolve(val), ms)
  })

  promise[CANCEL] = () => clearTimeout(timeoutId)

  return promise
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using delay as imported from redux-saga/effects would solve your issue in one line